# Prevent User from Leaving App

Tags: customization, kiosk-mode

I have developed an app for a job that will be used by their customers.

Each customer (Anonymous) enters there, uses app (tablet) and then leave.

The thing is that I want the users not to leave my app on tablet.

For this purpose I have blocked back button with a pass code but still the user can press home button, multi task button, or even swipe notification bar down and go to other locations.

Up to now I am thinking of a custom ROM that allows me block or remove all this possibilities. Although may be more simple ways than a custom ROM may be available that didn't reach to my mind.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance. TG.

Comment: Please note that asking for software recommendations or other off-site resources (including custom ROMs) is off-topic here. I've slightly adjusted your question to rather ask "how to achieve this". What you're looking for is kiosk-mode, so I've added that tag (you might wish to check other questions using that tag).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to set up kiosk-mode on Android is to use Google's [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/) which works for any Android devices running Android 5.1 or above.

To lock the device on one app, or on multiple app, you define a kiosk policy like below, it will disable the navigation buttons (sample copied from [Create a policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-policy#for_devices_running_multiple_apps_from_a_custom_launcher)):

```
"applications": [
 {
   "packageName": "com.example.app",
   "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
   "lockTaskAllowed": true,
   "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
 },
"persistentPreferredActivities": [
  {
    "receiverActivity": "com.example.app/.com.example.app.MainActivity",
    "actions": [
      "android.intent.action.MAIN"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "android.intent.category.HOME",
      "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    ]
  }
]
```